# Automatically Upload Job offers to Linkedin

Tags: linkedin-api, abap

I've read much about implementing LinkedIn into my website, but is it possible to upload job offers from an external software directly to LinkedIn?

I’m working with an SAP based recruiting management software. One of the function it is capable of, is to create job offers. But until now, they are only internal. I want to implement a function, which allows the user to automatically upload a job offer to LinkedIn.

Does LinkedIn provide some kind of support for such kind of work? XING for example, offers you documentations for a connection via API or XML. Is there something additional existing for LinkedIn?

Comment: What have you tried? Maybe have a look at https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api#

Comment: I spent several hours there, an in the developer section generally, but I wasn't able to find anything about posting jobs from the “outside”. There was something about job-Posts, but that seemed like some kind of function for statistics to me. I have to say, the structure of the API-Section in the site itself confuses me a little.
I just need to know, if it’s possible to post job-offers from an external software via XML or JSON. Sorry for being too clumsy to find it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it isn't available for the normal APIs.  They have a specific section based on their "Talent Solutions" that may be of interest.  Looks to be a paid program

https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/talent